# missing values when merging spatial data frame with regular dataframe

Tags: r, gis, shapefile, r-sf, rgdal

I am trying to add cancer cases by census tracts into a shape file.
the first thing I did was merge two data frame to create one so that they have the same data:
**

```
> head(cancercrosswalk)
       GEOID    Dohregion
1 3.6001e+11   3.6001E+11
2 3.6001e+11   3.6001E+11
3 3.6001e+11   3.6001E+11
4 3.6001e+11   3.6001E+11
5 3.6001e+11 36001DOH0001
6 3.6001e+11 36001DOH0001
```

**

```
> head(cancerdata)
     Dohregion observed_Bladder observed_Bone observed_Brain observed_Breast observed_Colorectal observed_Esophagus observed_Kidney
1 360010001001                2             0              0               0                   3                  0               1
2 360010001002                0             0              0               2                   2                  0               2
3 360010002001                0             0              0               9                   8                  0               3
4 360010002002                0             0              0               4                   1                  1               0
5 360010003001                0             0              0               5                   1                  0               1
6 360010003002                0             1              0               5                   4                  0               1
  observed_Larynx observed_Leukemias observed_Liver observed_Lung observed_Mesothelioma observed_Nasal observed_NHL observed_Oral
1               0                  1              4             2                     0              0            0             0
2               2                  0              1             4                     0              0            1             0
3               0                  0              1             9                     0              0            1             0
4               1                  1              0             2                     0              0            0             0
5               0                  1              0             8                     0              0            0             0
6               1                  0              2            10                     0              0            0             1
  observed_Other observed_Ovary observed_Pancreas observed_Prostate observed_Soft_Tissue observed_Stomach observed_Testis observed_Thyroid
1              4              0                 1                 2                    0                1               0                0
2              2              0                 1                 3                    0                1               1                0
3              8              0                 0                 8                    0                1               0                0
4              2              0                 0                 1                    0                2               0                0
5              4              0                 2                 2                    0                0               1                2
6              4              2                 3                 1                    0                0               0                0
  observed_Uterus observed_Total expected_Bladder expected_Bone expected_Brain expected_Breast expected_Colorectal expected_Esophagus
1               0             21        1.1907933    0.05341615      0.3420870        3.897930            2.031289          0.2463417
2               2             24        0.9554851    0.05899713      0.3366652        3.500111            1.758774          0.1927699
3               2             50        1.9320032    0.13779911      0.7932614        7.157767            3.546426          0.4175883
4               0             15        1.1485568    0.05037550      0.3169550        2.579577            1.723736          0.2299884
5               1             28        1.6505217    0.06077597      0.4212359        4.483157            2.712521          0.3221699
6               2             37        1.5212557    0.08610623      0.5076649        5.075406            2.677475          0.3108412
  expected_Kidney expected_Larynx expected_Leukemias expected_Liver expected_Lung expected_Mesothelioma expected_Nasal expected_NHL
1       0.8905821       0.1905469          0.8392223      0.4973385      3.233132            0.04572182     0.07521876    1.1188694
2       0.7414155       0.1473305          0.7532520      0.3900473      2.514994            0.03739868     0.06902838    0.9674379
3       1.6403917       0.3318865          1.6358432      0.8733376      5.159199            0.07350316     0.15132371    2.0350425
4       0.7901266       0.1788591          0.7569305      0.4464840      2.663298            0.04506314     0.06818121    0.9699708
5       1.1308030       0.2398039          1.0923065      0.6319331      4.104686            0.06344310     0.09878849    1.4669949
6       1.1462822       0.2374476          1.1573802      0.6336747      4.020863            0.05866436     0.10255844    1.4791360
  expected_Oral expected_Other expected_Ovary expected_Pancreas expected_Prostate expected_Soft_Tissue expected_Stomach expected_Testis
1     0.5471169       3.607037      0.3698598         0.7301899          3.480829            0.1789978        0.4535283       0.1234136
2     0.4535536       3.219043      0.3349575         0.5963126          2.492342            0.1730567        0.3782364       0.1275014
3     1.0024772       6.672465      0.6872987         1.1864065          6.055943            0.3869417        0.7815492       0.2915861
4     0.4925228       3.121445      0.2485737         0.6041984          3.567018            0.1644644        0.4008159       0.1312871
5     0.7020538       4.798143      0.4305209         0.9633933          4.368603            0.2317557        0.6013436       0.2123629
6     0.7053411       4.868844      0.4904034         0.9337788          4.330438            0.2583340        0.5870411       0.2042880
  expected_Thyroid expected_Uterus expected_Total highlight_Bladder highlight_Bone highlight_Brain highlight_Breast highlight_Colorectal
1        1.0418115       1.0234262       26.20870                 0              0               0                0                    0
2        1.0829889       0.8155581       22.09726                 0              0               0                0                    0
3        2.4903833       1.6936861       47.13411                 0              0               0                0                    0
4        0.9149126       0.6301347       22.24347                 0              0               0                0                    0
5        1.2859511       1.1414483       33.21472                 0              0               0                0                    0
6        1.5214978       1.2371847       34.15191                 0              0               0                0                    0
  highlight_Esophagus highlight_Kidney highlight_Larynx highlight_Leukemias highlight_Liver highlight_Lung highlight_Mesothelioma
1                   0                0                0                   0               1              1                      0
2                   0                0                0                   0               1              1                      0
3                   0                0                0                   0               1              1                      0
4                   0                0                0                   0               1              1                      0
5                   0                0                0                   0               0              0                      0
6                   0                0                0                   0               1              1                      0
  highlight_Nasal highlight_NHL highlight_Oral highlight_Ovary highlight_Pancreas highlight_Prostate highlight_Soft_Tissue highlight_Stomach
1               0             0              0               0                  0                  0                     0                 0
2               0             0              0               0                  0                  0                     0                 0
3               0             0              0               0                  0                  0                     0                 0
4               0             0              0               0                  0                  0                     0                 0
5               0             0              0               0                  0                  0                     0                 0
6               0             0              0               0                  0                  0                     0                 0
  highlight_Testis highlight_Thyroid highlight_Uterus male_pop female_pop total_pop
1                0                -1                0      471        523       994
2                0                -1                0      516        638      1154
3                0                 0                0     1262       1621      2883
4                0                 0                0      486        503       989
5                0                 0                0      590        601      1191
6                0                 0                0      794        891      1685
```

I then merged these two dataframes with the following script:

```
cancerdatacrosswalk <- merge(cancercrosswalk, cancerdata, by="Dohregion")
```

which gave me the following:

```
> head(cancerdatacrosswalk)
     Dohregion      GEOID observed_Bladder observed_Bone observed_Brain observed_Breast observed_Colorectal observed_Esophagus observed_Kidney
1 36001DOH0001 3.6001e+11                2             0              1               7                   9                  0               2
2 36001DOH0001 3.6001e+11                2             0              1               7                   9                  0               2
3 36001DOH0002 3.6001e+11                3             0              0               4                   3                  1               0
4 36001DOH0002 3.6001e+11                3             0              0               4                   3                  1               0
5 36001DOH0003 3.6001e+11                1             0              0               3                   3                  1               1
6 36001DOH0003 3.6001e+11                1             0              0               3                   3                  1               1
  observed_Larynx observed_Leukemias observed_Liver observed_Lung observed_Mesothelioma observed_Nasal observed_NHL observed_Oral
1               2                  0              7            10                     0              0            1             1
2               2                  0              7            10                     0              0            1             1
3               0                  0              1             3                     0              0            2             0
4               0                  0              1             3                     0              0            2             0
5               0                  2              0             4                     0              0            2             1
6               0                  2              0             4                     0              0            2             1
  observed_Other observed_Ovary observed_Pancreas observed_Prostate observed_Soft_Tissue observed_Stomach observed_Testis observed_Thyroid
1              6              0                 3                 4                    1                0               0                3
2              6              0                 3                 4                    1                0               0                3
3              6              0                 0                 5                    1                0               0                0
4              6              0                 0                 5                    1                0               0                0
5              2              0                 1                 6                    0                0               0                3
6              2              0                 1                 6                    0                0               0                3
  observed_Uterus observed_Total expected_Bladder expected_Bone expected_Brain expected_Breast expected_Colorectal expected_Esophagus
1               1             60        1.6142981    0.10604801      0.6236729        5.908864            3.098174          0.3536228
2               1             60        1.6142981    0.10604801      0.6236729        5.908864            3.098174          0.3536228
3               2             31        1.9369476    0.54237884      1.3475544        4.834760            3.375224          0.3583970
4               2             31        1.9369476    0.54237884      1.3475544        4.834760            3.375224          0.3583970
5               3             33        0.8915422    0.06715243      0.3460775        3.231097            1.680597          0.1993447
6               3             33        0.8915422    0.06715243      0.3460775        3.231097            1.680597          0.1993447
  expected_Kidney expected_Larynx expected_Leukemias expected_Liver expected_Lung expected_Mesothelioma expected_Nasal expected_NHL
1       1.3973082       0.2802778          1.3208814      0.7513557      4.202251            0.06146264     0.13492192    1.7393000
2       1.3973082       0.2802778          1.3208814      0.7513557      4.202251            0.06146264     0.13492192    1.7393000
3       1.2901389       0.2602064          2.1781671      0.7577139      4.574280            0.08588023     0.17334724    2.5207380
4       1.2901389       0.2602064          2.1781671      0.7577139      4.574280            0.08588023     0.17334724    2.5207380
5       0.7628971       0.1571715          0.7259757      0.4283296      2.398959            0.03353963     0.07268469    0.9710704
6       0.7628971       0.1571715          0.7259757      0.4283296      2.398959            0.03353963     0.07268469    0.9710704
  expected_Oral expected_Other expected_Ovary expected_Pancreas expected_Prostate expected_Soft_Tissue expected_Stomach expected_Testis
1     0.8758962       5.691519      0.5668703          1.011333          4.904616            0.3175835        0.6742324       0.3279035
2     0.8758962       5.691519      0.5668703          1.011333          4.904616            0.3175835        0.6742324       0.3279035
3     0.8749945       8.421422      0.7861456          1.123232          4.505722            0.7245306        0.7389003       1.2260567
4     0.8749945       8.421422      0.7861456          1.123232          4.505722            0.7245306        0.7389003       1.2260567
5     0.4822611       3.139914      0.3211993          0.566330          2.825828            0.1789735        0.3688901       0.2054874
6     0.4822611       3.139914      0.3211993          0.566330          2.825828            0.1789735        0.3688901       0.2054874
  expected_Thyroid expected_Uterus expected_Total highlight_Bladder highlight_Bone highlight_Brain highlight_Breast highlight_Colorectal
1         2.057894       1.4048219       39.42511                 0              0               0                0                    0
2         2.057894       1.4048219       39.42511                 0              0               0                0                    0
3         3.827066       1.2455196       47.70932                 0              0               0                0                    0
4         3.827066       1.2455196       47.70932                 0              0               0                0                    0
5         1.136775       0.8154357       22.00753                 0              0               0                0                    0
6         1.136775       0.8154357       22.00753                 0              0               0                0                    0
  highlight_Esophagus highlight_Kidney highlight_Larynx highlight_Leukemias highlight_Liver highlight_Lung highlight_Mesothelioma
1                   0                0                0                   0               1              1                      0
2                   0                0                0                   0               1              1                      0
3                   0                0                0                   0               0              0                      0
4                   0                0                0                   0               0              0                      0
5                   0                0                0                   0               1              0                      0
6                   0                0                0                   0               1              0                      0
  highlight_Nasal highlight_NHL highlight_Oral highlight_Ovary highlight_Pancreas highlight_Prostate highlight_Soft_Tissue highlight_Stomach
1               0             0              0               0                  0                  0                     0                 0
2               0             0              0               0                  0                  0                     0                 0
3               0             0              0               0                  0                  0                     0                 0
4               0             0              0               0                  0                  0                     0                 0
5               0             0              0               0                  0                  0                     0                 0
6               0             0              0               0                  0                  0                     0                 0
  highlight_Testis highlight_Thyroid highlight_Uterus male_pop female_pop total_pop
1                0                 0                0     1036       1150      2186
2                0                 0                0     1036       1150      2186
3                0                 0                0     3930       4318      8248
4                0                 0                0     3930       4318      8248
5                0                 0                0      587        690      1277
6                0                 0                0      587        690      1277
```

So far so Good. Then I merged this df to a spatial df by GEOID

```
newcensus <- merge(censustracts, cancerdatacrosswalk, by="GEOID")
```

But this produced NA's for all of the new columns in the spatial file.

```
> head(newcensus)
           GEOID STATEFP COUNTYFP TRACTCE    NAME             NAMELSAD MTFCC FUNCSTAT  ALAND   AWATER    INTPTLAT     INTPTLON Dohregion
1794 36047069601      36      047  069601  696.01  Census Tract 696.01 G5020        S 456923    47776 +40.6271699 -073.9153676      <NA>
1795 36047069602      36      047  069602  696.02  Census Tract 696.02 G5020        S 688168   172866 +40.6227610 -073.9092489      <NA>
1846 36047079801      36      047  079801  798.01  Census Tract 798.01 G5020        S 129680        0 +40.6600109 -073.9587186      <NA>
1847 36047079802      36      047  079802  798.02  Census Tract 798.02 G5020        S 106366        0 +40.6579906 -073.9613711      <NA>
1952 36047105801      36      047  105801 1058.01 Census Tract 1058.01 G5020        S 418443        0 +40.6492205 -073.8805957      <NA>
2014 36047990100      36      047  990100    9901    Census Tract 9901 G5020        S      0 17793788 +40.5649788 -074.0148235      <NA>
     observed_Bladder observed_Bone observed_Brain observed_Breast observed_Colorectal observed_Esophagus observed_Kidney observed_Larynx
1794               NA            NA             NA              NA                  NA                 NA              NA              NA
1795               NA            NA             NA              NA                  NA                 NA              NA              NA
1846               NA            NA             NA              NA                  NA                 NA              NA              NA
1847               NA            NA             NA              NA                  NA                 NA              NA              NA
1952               NA            NA             NA              NA                  NA                 NA              NA              NA
2014               NA            NA             NA              NA                  NA                 NA              NA              NA
     observed_Leukemias observed_Liver observed_Lung observed_Mesothelioma observed_Nasal observed_NHL observed_Oral observed_Other
1794                 NA             NA            NA                    NA             NA           NA            NA             NA
1795                 NA             NA            NA                    NA             NA           NA            NA             NA
1846                 NA             NA            NA                    NA             NA           NA            NA             NA
1847                 NA             NA            NA                    NA             NA           NA            NA             NA
1952                 NA             NA            NA                    NA             NA           NA            NA             NA
2014                 NA             NA            NA                    NA             NA           NA            NA             NA
     observed_Ovary observed_Pancreas observed_Prostate observed_Soft_Tissue observed_Stomach observed_Testis observed_Thyroid observed_Uterus
1794             NA                NA                NA                   NA               NA              NA               NA              NA
1795             NA                NA                NA                   NA               NA              NA               NA              NA
1846             NA                NA                NA                   NA               NA              NA               NA              NA
1847             NA                NA                NA                   NA               NA              NA               NA              NA
1952             NA                NA                NA                   NA               NA              NA               NA              NA
2014             NA                NA                NA                   NA               NA              NA               NA              NA
     observed_Total expected_Bladder expected_Bone expected_Brain expected_Breast expected_Colorectal expected_Esophagus expected_Kidney
1794             NA               NA            NA             NA              NA                  NA                 NA              NA
1795             NA               NA            NA             NA              NA                  NA                 NA              NA
1846             NA               NA            NA             NA              NA                  NA                 NA              NA
1847             NA               NA            NA             NA              NA                  NA                 NA              NA
1952             NA               NA            NA             NA              NA                  NA                 NA              NA
2014             NA               NA            NA             NA              NA                  NA                 NA              NA
     expected_Larynx expected_Leukemias expected_Liver expected_Lung expected_Mesothelioma expected_Nasal expected_NHL expected_Oral
1794              NA                 NA             NA            NA                    NA             NA           NA            NA
1795              NA                 NA             NA            NA                    NA             NA           NA            NA
1846              NA                 NA             NA            NA                    NA             NA           NA            NA
1847              NA                 NA             NA            NA                    NA             NA           NA            NA
1952              NA                 NA             NA            NA                    NA             NA           NA            NA
2014              NA                 NA             NA            NA                    NA             NA           NA            NA
     expected_Other expected_Ovary expected_Pancreas expected_Prostate expected_Soft_Tissue expected_Stomach expected_Testis expected_Thyroid
1794             NA             NA                NA                NA                   NA               NA              NA               NA
1795             NA             NA                NA                NA                   NA               NA              NA               NA
1846             NA             NA                NA                NA                   NA               NA              NA               NA
1847             NA             NA                NA                NA                   NA               NA              NA               NA
1952             NA             NA                NA                NA                   NA               NA              NA               NA
2014             NA             NA                NA                NA                   NA               NA              NA               NA
     expected_Uterus expected_Total highlight_Bladder highlight_Bone highlight_Brain highlight_Breast highlight_Colorectal highlight_Esophagus
1794              NA             NA                NA             NA              NA               NA                   NA                  NA
1795              NA             NA                NA             NA              NA               NA                   NA                  NA
1846              NA             NA                NA             NA              NA               NA                   NA                  NA
1847              NA             NA                NA             NA              NA               NA                   NA                  NA
1952              NA             NA                NA             NA              NA               NA                   NA                  NA
2014              NA             NA                NA             NA              NA               NA                   NA                  NA
     highlight_Kidney highlight_Larynx highlight_Leukemias highlight_Liver highlight_Lung highlight_Mesothelioma highlight_Nasal highlight_NHL
1794               NA               NA                  NA              NA             NA                     NA              NA            NA
1795               NA               NA                  NA              NA             NA                     NA              NA            NA
1846               NA               NA                  NA              NA             NA
```

Is there a way for me to force the values into the spatial data file? please advise

EDIT: I noticed the scientific notation issue, i fixed it to where there were whole numbers but the problem persists.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Getting all those NAs would usually happen if the by variables didn't match. Can you check to see if they really do match exactly? `cancercrosswalk$GEOID == censustracts$GEOID`

Comment: Hello Elin, I ran that line and i got back a bunch of falses. I then did this: `intersect(censustracts$GEOID, cancerdatacrosswalk$GEOID)
numeric(0)` I got back numeric 0. I dont understand, they both have GEOID as the same.

Comment: They may appear to be the same when printed but they are not really.  It could be that there is some truncation in one of them.  Perhaps try converting to integers or even strings (since they are IDs)?

Comment: all of the variables from (cancerdatacrosswalk) are integers, excepts for DOHREGION which is character

Comment: I only asked about GEOID in the two data frames since that is what is not matching.